# Laravel Passport Oauth route page not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have a problem here, on my Laravel project it's show me **page could not found** cause it's **//oauth** double slashses in front of **oauth** word

[image]

Anyone can help me out about this ?

Comment: What's the value for APP_URL in ENV ? Probably you might have placed "/" along with it. Remove that and try to check again.

Comment: here it's the .env APP_URL=http://site.url/public ..

Comment: Why you have added site.url/public instead of just domain. Like, APP_URL=http://{your_domain}

Comment: @JicksonJohnsonKoottala is right. Change `.env` line to be `APP_URL="https://site.url"`

Comment: i've change it but it's doesn't work ...